# Cant declare readonly property in main class?

Tags: c#

```
public class Program
{
    public readonly string val; // THIS IS AN ERROR?
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // get parameter value
        if (args.Length>0)
        {
            val = args[0];
```

Could you tell us why I get an error compiling this? And best way to put an argument value inside a const or readonly variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things to note here:

- readonly field  assignments can only occur as part of the declaration
  or in a constructor in the same class.
- your field is non-static, while your main function is static. You cannot set a    non-static variable in static context. A non-static field requires an instance of the class.

I suggest you to mark your field as static and assign a value to your variable where you're declaring

The following code should run

```
public class Program
{
    public static string val; // THIS IS AN ERROR?
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // get parameter value
        if (args.Length>0)
        {
           Program.val = args[0];
```

Comment: What does it have to do with the `Main` function being static? `Program` is not a static class.

Comment: In console applications the main function is the entry point of your program and it is called by the environment. Static functions can be called without instantiating an object/instance of a the class. 
See chapter 10 in the language specification: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf

Comment: That makes sense.

Comment: I understand but could you give us a way to make my code works? I like to make the first argument a const or a readonly unmutable variable if its possible..

Comment: @Chopnut Take a look at my answer, I think it's the most you'll get for locking down the value of your `val` string.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with the class it is in. You only have to initialize it with a value either in the declaration or in the constructor. (As it is readonly, you cannot assign it later.)

```
public readonly string val = "myString";
```

Comment: This is actually not true, since you can assign `readonly`s as with instanced values inside a constructor.

Comment: @Andrew It is true that you have to initialize it. But I did not say that this is possible in the constructor, too. Instead, I went for the simplest solution given OP's code. But I have edited my answer now to make that clear.

Comment: Always best to give the true answer, not just half of it.

Answer (score 1):

Readonly must be assigned to either on declaration or inside a constructor for that class. That's what makes it readonly.

Perhaps your best option is this

```
public string val {get; private set;}
```

that way it can only be set from within the Program class.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign it's value immediately.  Otherwise how could it be "read only?"